# How to know how many words a paragraph contains using Jquery or Javascript? What function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, space

How to know how many words a paragraph contains using Jquery or Javascript? What function?

For example, the sentence

> How to know how many words a paragraph
>   contains using Jquery or Javascript?

contains 13 words. How to count using Jquery or javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `textContent` (or `innerText` for IE) of the `p` element, and count the words, assuming that a *word* is a group of characters separated by a space.

You could do something like this:

```
function wordNumber (element) {
  var text = element.innerText || element.textContent;
  return text.split(' ').length;
}

alert(wordNumber(document.getElementById('paragraphId')));
```

Try the above snippet [here](http://jsbin.com/ohano).

Comment: This fails on text with newlines/tabs/multiple-spaces/etc in it, inside  `<pre>` elements or any element with css `white-space:pre;` set.

Answer (score 7):

If you take the word separator to be whitespace:

```
function wordCount(str) {
  return str.split(/\s+/).length
}

wordCount("How to know how many words \
           a paragraph contains using Jquery \
           or Javascript?"); // 13
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery:

```
$('p').text().split(' ').length
```